# Azure Data Factory v2: Activity execute pipeline output

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to reference the output of an executed pipeline in the activity "Execute pipeline"?

I.e.: master pipeline executes 2 pipelines in sequence. The first pipeline generates an own created run_id that needs to be forwarded as a parameter to the second pipeline.

I've read the documentation and checked that the master pipeline log the output of the first pipeline, but it looks like that this is not directly possible?

We've used until now only 2 pipelines without a master pipeline, but we want to re-use the logic more. Currently we have 1 pipeline that calls the next pipeline and forwards the run_id.

Update 2023-03-31
As of early 2023 we can have output from a pipeline, via using the newly introduced system variable 'Pipeline Return Value'.

Official documentation is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-return-value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ExecutePipline currently cannot pass anything from its insides to its output.  You can only get the runID or name.

For some weird reason, the output of ExecutePipeline is returned not as a JSON object but as a string.  So if you try to select a property of output like this `@activity('ExecutePipelineActivityName').output.something` then you get this error:

*Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'*

I found that I had to use the following to get the run ID:
`@json(activity('ExecutePipelineActivityName').output).pipelineRunId`

Comment: As of early 2023 we can have output from a pipeline, via using the newly introduced system variable 'Pipeline Return Value'.

Official documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-return-value

Answer (score 2):

The execute pipeline activity is just another activity with outputs that can be captured by other activities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity#type-properties

If you want to use the runId of the pipeline executed previosly, it would look like this:

```
@activity('ExecutePipelineActivityName').output.pipeline.runId
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin for your help. Can I ask you to specify more in details what's the DataFactory operator/activity that we can use to recover the Output of a Pipeline, given that we know the "pipelineRunId". Thanks

Comment: You can use this anywhere you need, it depends on what you are trying to do with the output. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I would like to invoke a Pipeline that contains a CopyActivity task. Basically, from the parent pipeline, I would like to retrieve the output of the child pipeline, leveraging the "pipelineRunId", to read the output of the CopyActivity and check metadata info like rowsRead, rowsCopied and rowsSkipped. Thanks

Comment: @pippobaudos, have you had your question answered? I am running into the same question. I'd like to see an example how the activity output is used.