# Azure Data Factory Lookup and For Each

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Data Factory Pipeline that I want to have iterate through the rows of a SQL Lookup activity. I have narrowed the query down to three columns and 500 rows.

I understand that to reference a value in the table I use:

```
@{activity('lookupActivity').output.value[row#].colname}
```

However, the for each needs to have something to iterate over. My first guess is to set some array variable to the rows of the returned sql query. So what do I set that variable to?

```
@{activity('lookupActivity').output.value?
```

Lastly, it looks like almost all data is represented as a json in ADF, is this true? And how could I view the output of this look up as a json so I can understand what my dynamic content needs to look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right that everything (nearly) is JSON.  (Exception: [Azure Data Factory v2: Activity execute pipeline output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412439/azure-data-factory-v2-activity-execute-pipeline-output)/62038291#62038291)

So you can put your `@activity('lookupActivity').output.value` which is an array into the foreach activity on the settings tab, like this

[image]

Then inside your foreach loop, you reference the current value of one of the columns as `@item().colname`.

Comment: What if needed to pass it through a web activity json as "foo" : ["bar"]. Would you recommend "foo" : @array(activity('lookup').output.value)?

Comment: I haven't tested it but I expect it would be `"foo": @string(activity('lookup').output.value)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the output value to for each activity and go through one at a time. You can do sequential or parallel depending on your needs.